# Как отформатировать тип POINT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis

Как вместо:

```
0101000020E61000000000000000000040000000000000F03F
```

Изменить его на (x y)

Использую SQLAlchemy и geoalchemy для работы с базой данных.

База данных: PostgreSQL

Comment: В geoalchemy2 есть метод `to_shape` (from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape) - он по идее должен вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое